# DateTime in MVC Controller Class for DisplayFor, EditorFor, and HiddenFor HTML helpers

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a column in SQL Server named *date_updated*. In an MVC application, at /Controllers/Example.cs, I've the following:

```
    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime date_updated
    {
        get
        {
            return _date;
        }
        set
        {
            _date = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

At /Views/Example/Edit.cshtml, I've a DisplayFor, EditorFor, and HiddenFor HTML helper.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.date_updated)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.date_updated)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.date_updated)
```

Let's say today's date is 08/13/2016 and the record with ID="1" in SQL has last_updated="07/01/2016". The DisplayFor and EditorFor HTML helpers will display today's date (08/13/2016) and the HiddenFor HTML helper will display the date in SQL (07/01/2016).

- DisplayFor = 08/13/2016
- EditorFor = 08/13/2016
- HiddenFor = 07/01/2016

I would very much like the DisplayFor, EditorFor, and HiddenFor HTML helpers to all display the date in SQL (07/01/2016). I am not sure how to get the DisplayFor and EditorFor HTML helpers to display the *date_updated* from SQL.

Comment: In such case why do you have this in property setter `_date = DateTime.Now;`?

Comment: I have placed _date = DateTime.Now; inside of the setter property so that when navigating to www.example.com/Example/Edit/1 and clicking Save, the DateTime in SQL is updated to the current DateTime. Is there some other approach that is better suited for this objective?

Comment: What you claiming is not possible (unless you have omitted some relevant code). The value of `date_updated` can only return `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.MinValue`) since you cannot set its value. And there is no difference between `EditorFor()` and `HiddenFor()` in what they will display (unless you have a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `DateTime`) And unless you have altered the value of the property in the controller after `ModelState` values have been initialized, will be the same as `DisplayFor()`

Comment: Thanks guys, your comments helped me to discover a solution. I'll answer my question in case it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with in case it helps others. There are 2 columns in SQL:

- date_published
- date_updated

When editing a record, the objective is to keep the current DateTime in SQL for date_published, and to update the DateTime in SQL for date_updated to the current DateTime.

I modified the /Controllers/Example.cs file to have the following.

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime date_published { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime date_updated { get; set; }
```

I then added HiddenFor HTML helpers to the /View/Example/Edit file for both the date_published and date_updated columns. I set the value of the date_updated to System.DateTime.Now.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.date_published)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.date_updated, new { @Value=System.DateTime.Now })
```

Viewing the source of www.example.com/App/Edit/1 will include hidden HTML tags for both the date_published and date_updated columns. The date_published hidden tag contain the value of the DateTime from SQL. The date_updated tag contains 2 values, one for the DateTime from SQL and another for the System.DateTime.Now. Although it is not ideal to have 2 values in the date_updated tag, it achieves the goal. The date_published will retain the DateTime from SQL, and date_updated will update the record in SQL to the current DateTime.

```
<input id="date_published" name="date_published" type="hidden" value="7/01/2016 1:23:27 PM" />
<input Value="08/13/2016 13:50:42" id="date_updated" name="date_updated" type="hidden" value="7/01/2016 1:23:27 AM" />
```